# loop.run_forever() in a restful interface? How to keep asyncio loop alive over multiple restful calls

Tags: flask, websocket, python-asyncio, flask-restful

Is there a way to keep an asyncio loop alive between restful interface calls in flask?

In my case, I have a restful interface in flask which uses asyncio to access another websocket. I'd like to avoid that the asyncio look is again newly instantiated each time a restful call is made.

Is there a way to keep it alive between multiple restful calls?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try Python library `threading`. Something like:

```
from threading import Thread, Event

class AsyncIO(Thread):
    def run(self):
        something.loop_forever()

asyncio_thread = Thread()
asyncio_stop = Event()

if not asyncio_thread.is_alive():
    asyncio_thread = AsyncIO()
    asyncio_thread.start()

# The code is executed here and AsyncIO is running
```

Don't forget to replace `something` by your reference of AsyncIO

Comment: Very interesting idea. Few comments. Should it be `something.run_forever()`? What exactly is something? Would it be `asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())` and then `something = asyncio.get_event_loop()`. Can I then retrieve that loop globally and connect different coroutines to it? I added a bit more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61511708/restful-to-serve-a-websocket-architecture-with-a-single-thread-and-asyncio